Install usbipd on ubuntu for wsl2
I am trying to see if wsl can detect my laptop's camera, and I saw that usbipd is the tool for that. However, any solution found online did not work or was not really explained fully. How do I actually install this on wsl it's drving me nuts. Thank you in advance. I am running ubuntu on wsl2 on a Lenovo Thinkpad L15.

Did you install the correct Windows software? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb

what version of WSL are you running?  List the things that you tried.  What laptop (manufacturer, model, and part number)  and camera chipset do you have?
